# I have to upload a file to the server using a java swing

Tags: java, http, swing

I am very much new to swing .
I need to upload a file to the Jboss server using a java swing . How can i go about in the task ?

Thanks

Comment: Swing has nothing to do with file upload, you need some Java HTTP client, for example: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/features.html

Comment: Thanks for the answers  , i am using JFileChooser() class to the choose the file from my system ,now i need to upload that file to the server ...

how do i go about ...

Answer (score 1):

As Max already mentioned Swing is a UI library. 
You have to create HTTP post and write your file into the output stream, i.e. do something like:

```
URL url = new URL("http://host/filehandler");
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setUseCaches(false);
con.setRequestMethod("POST");

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filePath);
OutputStream out = con.getOutputStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
while (-1 != (n = in.read(in))) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, n);
}
```

Obviously `http://host/filehandler` should be mapped to something that is ready to receive this post and deal with it. For example servlet that implements `doPost()` and saves the stream as file.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have used your JFileChooser and have selected the file you wish to upload you must connect to the server. Your server must have an ftp-server running. You have to have an account and password. Get the `commons-net-2.2.jar` from apache, in order to be able to create FTPClient.

Here you will find more about FTPClient:

http://commons.apache.org/net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html

Your code must look like this:

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
    client.connect("192.168.1.123");
    client.login("myaccount", "myPasswd");
    int reply = client.getReplyCode();
    if (!client.isConnected()) {
        System.out.println("FTP server refused connection." + reply);
        client.disconnect();
        System.exit(1);
    } else {
        System.out.println("FTP server connected." + reply);
    }
    // Create an InputStream for the file to be uploaded
    String filename = "sp2t.c";
    fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
    // Store file to server
    client.storeFile(filename, fis);
    client.logout();
}  catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
} finally {
    try {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
        client.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```